# Facebook Like Box Background Issue with Internet Explorer - Light theme regardless

Tags: facebook, internet-explorer, facebook-likebox

Having a wee headache with implementing a FB likebox in Internet Exploder.I know it sounds simple but for some reason I can't seem to get away from the light themed background.

http://samrowsell.co.uk/emerald/contact.php

Background color fine in Chrome, Opera, FF and Safari but not transparent in IE !

Any help met with gratitude!

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you mean you need the background colour of the "like box" to be green in IE?

I can see you're setting the background colour on the #likebox-frame. Have you tried replacing the

```
background-color: #214401;
```

to

```
background-color: #214401!important;
```

That might override it?

Comment: Thanks but alas no - the box is initially the correct color until the facebook likebox grey background is inherited....